# Multiple regression with many observations per case

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

I need to analyse the results of a psychology experiment which had a repeated measures design, i.e. all subjects underwent both treatment A and treatment B. There are 27 subjects with many trials (observations) per subject. The trials are independent (i.e. no learning effects are expected). There are three IV which are categorical and dichotomous. The DV is continuous. I want to conduct a multiple regression. The regression needs to incorporate the fact that there are a number of observations per subject. What type of regression should I use in this case?

Comment: Mixed-effects models can probably do this. Look at the lmer (or nlme) packages in R.

Comment: Thanks. I am using STATA, which will be alright as well, I reckon.